# JPA/Hibernate - Sharing EntityManager's

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

Is it possible in Spring/JPA (using Hibernate as the provider) to share EntityManager's across threads? (this is for testing purposes)

To give more detail, in standard @Transactional Spring test with a JpaTransactionManager, I'd like to share the *Spring-test-created* EntityManager with an isolated application under test (well, isolated aside from sharing the same configuration, transactionManager, etc... that is!)

Is there a way I could configure the JpaTransactionManager (or something else that it uses under-the-hood) so that when that application requests an EntityMananger it will return the same one used for the test case? (the application can also present a special identifier for the transactionManager telling it what EntityManager to provide if needed)

Comment: EntityManager instances are not thread-safe

Comment: That's ok, my application/test already synchronizes between the two (any invocation/use of the application from my test is a blocking operation, so there's no contention problem there...)

Comment: I believe JPA(Hibernate) and transaction managers and related components stores quite a lot of information in per-thread manner.  I really doubt if the application can run flawlessly if you share EM like that.  Btw, I still don't get the reason for doing so.  Can you give more information on what you are trying to achieve?  Normally we won't test like that, and even for integration testing, you should try to put it under same thread, or use other way to deal with data setup/cleanup.